# Printing special commit hash references in Git

Tags: git

Git provides "friendly names" for referencing some frequently used commit hashes like `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`.

I was wondering if there is a standard way of printing what these friendly identifiers point to?

Comment: `git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the above files are simple a metadata of git.

- [**`HEAD`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716) - The current commit in the current branch points to. To fully understand what [**`HEAD`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716) is [read this detaled post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716)
- **`FETCH_HEAD`** - a short-lived ref, to keep track of what has been fetched from the remote repository
- **`ORIG_HEAD`** - previous state of `HEAD`
- **`MERGE_HEAD`** - records the commit(s) which you are merging into your branch when you run git merge.
- **`CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`** records the commit which you are cherry-picking when you run git cherry-pick.

You can always use simple cat file:

```
cat .git/HEAD
cat .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

[image]

---

You can use any of the above to view the content of the commit with the `git show` command. This will print out the content of the commit.

```
# To view the latest commit message
git show HEAD --oneline

# To view the latest commit content
git show HEAD
```

and so on ....

Comment: Nice, `git show HEAD --oneline` is what I was looking for. I would appreciate if you could mention this at the top of your answer since it is much better than `cat`ing around refs. But I do appreciate the depth provided. :)

Comment: Better brief to different `HEAD`. +1

Comment: If this is whats you was looking for please be kind to accept this answer. update as you requested. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`git rev-parse <anything>` will try to resolve a commit.

As [@CodeWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598/codewizard) notes, you can also inspect the contents of those files under `.git/` to see how they work.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of `rev-parse`; +1!